# Postgres conversion from Oracle SQL

Tags: postgresql, regexp-like

Recently our company have started using Postgres.

I have the following code:

```
instr(upper(mname), dd.drug) > 0
 and regexp_like(upper(mname),
                           '(^|[^A-Z]+)' || dd.drug || '([^A-Z]+|$)')
```

How can I convert the same into Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what the Oracle expression does, but I think the following should do the same in Postgres:

```
strpos(upper(mname), dd.drug) > 0
  and upper(mname) ~ '(^|[^A-Z]+)' || dd.drug || '([^A-Z]+|$)'
```

The `~` is Postgres' [regex operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP). If you want a case **in**sensitive match, you can also use `~*`

The first check (using `instr` or `strpos`) seems unnecessary to me though. I think you can remove it completely.

Comment: I used this : upper(mname) ~ '(^|[^A-Z]+)' || 'compu' || '([^A-Z]+|$)'   It gave me an error :   SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text
  Position: 121   I am trying to find term that exactly matches particular word.  Ex : I want to find exact word "compu" ...I dont want any character to preceed or succeed it. So "decompu" or "computer" should not be in my result set.

Answer (score 0):

where upper(mname) ~  '\ycompu\y' ;